# Saved funnels not visible to other users in Yahoo Flurry Explorer

Tags: flurry, flurry-analytics

Made a few Funnels in Flurry Explorer and saved them. I can see them, but the other members of my team can't see them. Same the other way around, saved funnels don't seem to be shared between users of the same team. Is this happening to anyone? is this a bug? or maybe I have to enable something? I've looked into every menu and researched, but no solution seems to be available.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

This is not a bug but rather a feature request we are working on.

The explorer and real time dashboard tools are still in a preview status and we are adding to it over time.

Thanks for your patience on this important request.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I'll just use the current version in the meantime then.